# Rails fetch outlook mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook

I am building my rails application in that I am trying to fetch outlook mails using **viewpoint**but unable to do so.I am getting this error when I am trying to access folder .

```
Unknown key: version = 1
Unknown key: version = 1
```

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

At this line: **@folders = cli.folders**

outlooks_controller:

```
 require 'viewpoint'

    include Viewpoint::EWS

    class OutlooksController < ApplicationController


    def index
        endpoint = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&ct=1409066173&rver=6.1.6206.0&sa=1&ntprob=-1&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2F%3Fowa%3D1%26owasuffix%3Dowa%252f&id=64855&snsc=1&cbcxt=mail'
        user = 'username'
        pass = 'pass'

        cli = Viewpoint::EWSClient.new endpoint, user, pass
        @folders = cli.folders     #<---- exception here

        puts "hhhhhhhhh#{cli}"
     end

   end
```

[stacktrace]

```
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/ews_soap_response.rb:31:in `envelope'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/ews_soap_response.rb:39:in `body'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/ews_soap_response.rb:43:in `response'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/ews_soap_response.rb:47:in `response_messages'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/ews_soap_response.rb:80:in `simplify!'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/ews_soap_response.rb:27:in `initialize'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/parsers/ews_parser.rb:32:in `new'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/parsers/ews_parser.rb:32:in `parse'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/exchange_web_service.rb:221:in `parse_soap_response'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/connection.rb:74:in `dispatch'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/exchange_web_service.rb:212:in `do_soap_request'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/soap/exchange_data_services.rb:503:in `find_folder'
viewpoint (1.0.0) lib/ews/folder_accessors.rb:45:in `folders'
app/controllers/outlooks_controller.rb:13:in `index'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
logging (2.0.0) lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:448:in `call'
logging (2.0.0) lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:448:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if this is a bug in the gem itself. There's an issue opened here, where you might find more information: https://github.com/WinRb/Viewpoint/issues/166

Comment: @prateek read the information that Cereal provided in his answer. If this really is a bug with the gem, then asking on StackOverflow will not help. Try to ask for help (a possible monkey-patch) in the issue's thread. Or on the gem's mailing list (if they have one).